# Python3: List comprehension with named function definition possible?

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I'm using html-requests library but the library-specific knowledge doesn't matter that much in this question

```
results = asession.run(*[lambda m=j: get_size(m) for j in i])
```

`asession.run(f1, f2, f3, ...)` asynchronously runs `f1()`,`f2()`,`f3()`, and so on, returning `[f3(), f1(), f2()]` (returned list order varies)

The problem is, my `get_size` function can throw an error.

So I'd like to set some fallback value.
But with lambda expression, there's no way to insert try-except block. (lambda function only allows return value after :, not expression)

Instead of

```
[lambda m=j: get_size(m) for j in i]
```

Is the following kind of code impossible?  (of course the following code is syntactically wrong)

```
[def fn(m=j): try: return get_size(m) except: return 0 for j in i]
```

Is the following the only way?

```
def fn(m):
    try:
        return get_size(m)
    except:
        return 0
[lambda m=j: fn(m) for j in i]
```

I like some one-line list comprehension in my case and wonder there is any way to use named function definition (anything except lambda because lambda only allows return value hence is limited) inside list comprehension.

Comment: I wish there were exception fallback one liner like this: ```a = f1() orElse 8```.
Why doesn't this kind of thing exist? Because this is a bad idea or not pythonic probably? Why?

Comment: Actually, that does exist. You can do 'or', 'and',  if else all in one line. `>>> x = lambda: 0; a = x() or 1; print(a)`, `>>> a = x() if x() else 1; print(a)`. If this is what you want, I can craft out an answer to match your usecase.

Comment: @ThuYeinTun I know ```or``` but that doesn't help in case of exception. Am I wrong? As far as I know, try-except block is a must when it comes to exception, no other shortcut...

Comment: Yes, try except is required to handle exception, and it's the only way. You need to have a function that handes the exception and return value, not exception. Then you can use the `or` to select the value, or `if`.

Comment: I believe as well that the latest option you stated is the only possible way using exceptions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know what value of `m` causes the error (Eg. `len(m)` is 0) i.e. `Condition`, then you can use a lambda expression like so

```
f = lambda m : get_size(m) if not Condition else 0
[f(j) for j in i]
```

Comment: I think OP wants to know if there's an EAFP approach rather than a LBYL one... But yes, what you suggested might work under that specific condition.

Comment: I'd like to know there is way to write anonymous function capable of more than 2 expression (not just return). Javascript has it. Python doesn't have? The reason I need anonymous function? Because I want to put the functions inside list comprehension.

Comment: Isn't your code equivalent to ```[lambda m=j: get_size(m) for j in i if not Condition else 0]```?

Comment: Anonymous functions in python are called lambda expressions. **A lambda expression can have only one expression**, so nope.

Comment: Yes, it's equivalent. But yours is syntactically wrong i.e you'll get an error with that code.

Comment: @Arbitrary you can put any type of function inside a list comprehension, not just lambdas, you might be trying to solve the wrong problem. It's impossible to get try except or multiple statements inside one lambda function.